# BIGINT datatype and SELECT in pyodbc

Tags: sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I have created a MS ACCESS table through python using the pyodbc module, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [whole] 
(
    wholeID COUNTER PRIMARY KEY, 
    bin_str VARCHAR(65), 
    twos_comp VARCHAR(65), 
    denary BIGINT, 
    hexadecimal VARCHAR(17)
)
```

Note that the `BIGINT` data type was used for the `denary` column (the usual `INTEGER` datatype is just too small for my conversions), however when I try to query this table, I end up getting a strange format back (despite me checking that everything is saved correctly in the MS Access file as can be seen in image).

Do I just have to resort to using `INTEGER`?

[image: output 1]

[image: output 2]

[image: Access Table]

When I run this line of code via pyodbc:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [whole] 
WHERE [{}] LIKE '{}'
```

the resultant value for the `denary` column when I use `cursor.fetchall()` is in a strange format, for instance: what would usually be "747" becomes "˫\x00\x00\x00", what would usually be "700707" becomes "넣\n\x00\x00".

EDIT: I have just tried using the `INTEGER` datatype and the output is correct, but I really need the convenient `BIGINT` data type - is there any way to make it work?

Comment: "The BigInteger type is an immutable type that represents an arbitrarily large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower bounds." ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-8.0)).  what is the exact limit you want to apply to this **_convenient_** data type ?

Comment: Why not use: [Long Integer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/set-the-field-size-ba65e5a7-2e6f-4737-8e72-36b93f966a33#:~:text=is%20two%20bytes.-,Long%20Integer,-%E2%80%94%20For%20integers%20tha), which "For integers that range from -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647. Storage requirement is four bytes."

Comment: 1. How can I apply the limit?

Comment: 2. Long integer has quite a small range for my program

Comment: (Let me re-ask, with other words:)  What is the maximum value you need to store?

Comment: The highest it can go without causing errors with pyodbc or access. I read online that the maximum value for BIGINT is 2^63 -1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: So, you need to use the equivalent data type for MS ACCESS: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/using-the-large-number-data-type-5b623f6e-641d-4e97-8bdf-b77bae076f70    (and read the info on that page about what is exactly supported, like [Before you start using the Large Number data type, It’s very important that you understand the impact it could have on your Access databases.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/using-the-large-number-data-type-5b623f6e-641d-4e97-8bdf-b77bae076f70#:~:text=Before%20you%20start%20using%20the%20Large%20Number%20data%20type)

Comment: Try adding [this code](https://pastebin.com/N5qXzC7s) to your script after you have opened your connection and see if it helps.

Comment: @GordThompson nothing changed unfortunately

Comment: Okay, I'd suggest that you ask on [GitHub](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/discussions) and include an [ODBC trace](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Troubleshooting-%E2%80%93-Generating-an-ODBC-trace-log) for running a simple query like `SELECT [denary] FROM [whole] WHERE [wholeID] = 9`

Comment: Resolved on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/discussions/1307).